# Error: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, kimurai

I keep getting this error. I'm very confused. This is when I try and scrape a website.

Error: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Here is the scraper class

```
class RestaurantsScraper < Kimurai::Base
    @name = "restaurants_scraper"
    @driver = :selenium_chrome
    @start_urls = ["https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g31892-Rogers_Arkansas.html"]

    def parse(response, url:, data: {})
        response.xpath("//div[@class=_1llCuDZj]").each do |a|
            request_to :parse_repo_page, url: absolute_url(a[:href], base: url)
        end
    end



    def parse_repo_page(response, url:, data: {})
            item = {}
            item["title"] = t.css('a._15_ydu6b')&.text&.squish&.gsub('[^0-9].', '')
            item["type"] = t.css('span._1p0FLy4t')&.text&.squish
            item["reviews"] = t.css('span.w726Ki5B').text&.squish
            item["top_reviews"] = t.css('a._2uEVo25r _3mPt7dFq').text&.squish

            Restaurant.where(item).first_or_create
            byebug
    end
end
```

Here is my /scrape in my controller page

```
    url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g31892-Rogers_Arkansas.html"
    response = RestaurantsScraper.parse!(:parse, url: "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g31892-Rogers_Arkansas.html")
    if response[:status] == :completed && response[:error].nil?
      flash.now[:notice] = "Successfully scraped url"
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = response[:error]
    end
  rescue StandardError => e
    flash.now[:alert] = "Error: #{e}"
  end
```

Here is the error
[image: error]

Comment: If you look at the rails log it will show you a stacktrace and show you where this error is occurring. That screen shot of a rescued error does not do much for debugging. BTW this error is more than likely related to one of the objects you are calling `[](val)` on is actually an `Array` rather than a `Hash` (Most likely candidate is `response[:status]` because `xpath("//div[@class=_1llCuDZj]")` is going to return an `Array` like object

Comment: I checked the console and its not giving me anything. I changed the response[:status] to response["status"]. Is that what you meant? @engineersmnky

Comment: Remove this `rescue StandardError => e; flash.now[:alert] = "Error: #{e}"` and you will see the error. And no that change will result in "no implict conversion of String into Integer" the issue is that `parse` returns an `Array` like structure but you are trying to use it like a `Hash`. I am not sure what library is providing the parsing but if it is `nokogiri` then `response` is a [`Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet) because that is what `xpath` will return